Show the smoothness of an operator on vector bundle
Let $(E,\bar{\partial},K)\to X$ be a rank $n$ holomorphic vector bundle over X with a backgroud metric $K$. Let $S_{K}$ be the real vector subbundle of the selfadjoint sections of $End(E)$ with respect to $K$. Given a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, define an operator $F:S_{K}\to S_{K}$ as follow: given a smooth section $s$ of $S_{K}$, pointwisely, $s(x)$ can be diagonalized with eigenvalue $\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n}$, then we define the eigenvalues of F(s)(x) by $f(\lambda_{i})$. Can one show that $F(s)$ is indeed a smooth section of $S_{K}$?
I proceed in this way, smoothness is a local problem, locally, say in a neighborhood $U$, choose an othonormal frame of $E$ with respect to which $s$ is represented by a smooth Hermitian metrix valued function $s: U\to Herm(n)$. Then I get into trouble to show that $F(s)$ is also a smooth Hermitian metrix valued function. My idea is to find a new frame such that $s$ is uniformly diagonalized with respect to this frame. In order to do that, I have tried to show that the eigenvalue functions are smooth but I failed because if we have multiple eigenvalues at some points, it is possible that the eigenvalue function is not smooth at that point. This means we might also fail to find such a smooth frame.
